# What are the most appropriate times of day to perform puja to lord Vishnu?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puja, lakshmi, muhurta

I read that the most appropriate time for puja for Lord Shiva is Arunodaya muhurta, that Nishita muhurta is the time to perform puja for the goddess Lakshmi, and that the best time to perform puja for Lord Vishnu is "in the evening" — which, at the time, I understood to be around sunset.

But now I can't find any information about performing Vishnu puja around sunset, though, and instead quite a lot of sources recommend puja during Nishita muhurta.

It makes sense that the time of day most apt for Lakshmi puja might also be a good time for Vishnu puja, but I'd thought Nishita muhurta was *primarily* dear to Lakshmi, rather than to Vishnu, which makes me feel like there must be another time of day most appropriate to Vishnu that I am just not aware of. Or is Nishita primarily dear to Vishnu, and that is why it is also used for Lakshmi puja?

(I'm also curious as to why Pradosh puja is held after sunset when Arunodaya muhurta is seen as the most appropriate time for Shiva puja, but it's perhaps a separate question...)

What is the most appropriate time of day to perform puja for Lord Vishnu? Are there any other times of day that are also good for such observances? Is Nishita muhurta primarily for Lakshmi, or Vishnu, or both (equally)?

*P.S. If there are any materials I can refer to for extra reading, in order to understand this better, I'd be grateful for any pointers. And apologies if my question is a little confusing — I am indeed confused.*